# Find the value of $\frac{\sqrt2 + \sqrt6}{\sqrt{2 + \sqrt3}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, radicals

> Find the value of $\dfrac{\sqrt2 + \sqrt6}{\sqrt{2 + \sqrt3}}$.

My book is showing that this problem has an **exact** integer value solutions, but I was unable to find it.  How can we prove that it has integer solutions, and which integer is its solution?

Comment: **Hint:** [Rationalize](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/rationalize-denominator.html) the denominator.

Comment: i have tried but solution i find was not integer.

Comment: Sorry I misread your question. I just noticed that the square-root applies to the _entire_ denominator.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) when asking questions on this site.

Comment: $$\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}=\sqrt{\big(\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}\big)^2}$$

Comment: an4s thanks. i am new to this website so didn't know about this.

Answer (score 9):

I presume you mean
$$\frac{\sqrt2+\sqrt6}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}}?$$
If you call that $a$, then
$$a^2=\frac{2+2\sqrt{12}+6}{2+\sqrt3}=\frac{8+4\sqrt3}{2+\sqrt3}=4$$
so that $a=2$.

Comment: also the solution should contain -2 because of square.

Comment: @VaibhavPankhala:  $-2$ would be an [extraneous solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions), because $a$ is obviously positive

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**  $(1+\sqrt3)^2=2(2+\sqrt3)$